# Using custom domain for aws api gateway endpoint in mumbai

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, custom-domain

I have a aws api gateway hosted in mumbai(ap-south-1). I am trying to add a custom domain to the endpoint.

I created a ACM certificate in the same region and created a Custom Domain Name in the api gateway. The api gateway allowed me to use the ACM certificate only in regionalised(ap-south-1) endpoint configuration and not edge(us-east-1) optimised configuration. This is resulting in a target domain in the format as

`*.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

and not in the cloudfront format like

`*.cloudfront.net`

After creating the custom domain name(api.mydomain.com) I tried to add it to the hosted zone in route53.

When I try to Create Record Set using target domain in above format(*.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com), I am getting an error

`The record set could not be saved because:
- Alias Target contains an invalid value.`

[image]

I tried by creating the certificate in us-east-1 and creating an edge optimised endpoint. Here I got the cloudfront endpoint. But when I try to access the endpoint, I am getting forbidden exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that we have to use the certificate from us-east-1(N. Virginia) region and get the cloudfront endpoint it self. I am not sure why they allow regional endpoints if they don't support them in route 53.

For the forbidden error I was not using the correct url(used v1 in endpoint creation).

Comment: Hi @tharun  I am having same issue. I am having the certificate in same region but still getting cert issue. Can you please add more details.

Comment: @A_01 sometime it takes time for the cert to reflect. I will try to add more details.